# Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\View::make()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4.16 While using make method of View class i am getting undefined method error.

```
  public function Index()
{
    return View::make('stats');
}
```

Comment: Try either `return \View::make("stats")` (namespacing issue) or `return view("stats");` (non-namespaced function usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this to the top of the class:

```
use View;
```

If it doesn't work then it looks like you didn't install the project. You need to run `composer install` or `composer update` command which will download and install all dependencies into the `vendor` directory.

Another thing to check is `config/app.php` should have this line:

```
'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
```

Alternatively, you could use helper:

```
return view('stats');
```

But it will work only if porject is installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because make() method doesn't exist anywhere in your code. If you want to go from controller to view you can use simply:

```
public function Index() {
    return view('stats'); 
}
```

It will go to your status blade view by accessing your url request.

Comment: I am writing as an SO reviewer. You should please bear in mind that programmers might read your answer many times in future and would much appreciate an English description of why your code works. Would you please add some notes?

Comment: @Bill Bell: Done!

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

return view('path.to.your.directory');

Answer (score 1):

Just use Facade instead. Check how it works and then check what is wrong with View first. And I hope you are not using another template engine as Twig for example, cause if yes then you have definitely use Facade or check how the View factory is working, I think it requires template engine in the constructor ...

Just use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it:

```
return view('stats');
```